# Calculate sample size given Conditional Probability and level of significance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

On the basis of a pilot study, it was found that the predation
probability for dark-coloured moths on a dark background is 0.10,
in contrast to 0.90 on a light background.
What should be the sample size if you wish to test the hypothesis that the
the predation probability on a dark background is significantly smaller than
that on a light background at one percent level of significance (p<0.01)?